# Is the Galois correspondence still valid if automorphisms aren't required to be the identity on the base field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $E$ be a finite extension of $F$, and $\mathrm{Aut}(E|F)$ be the group of those automorphisms of $E$, which take $F$ to itself (but not necessarily identity  on $F$.

Let $X$ be the collection of intermediate fields $K$ between $E$ and $F$ (i.e. $F\subseteq K\subseteq E$). Then $\mathrm{Aut}(E|F)$ acts naturally on $X$.

Let $Y$ be the collection of subgroups of $\mathrm{Aut}(E|F)$.

**Question:** Is there natural one-to-one correspondence between $X$ and $Y$?

While looking back at the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, there we consider the automorphisms of an extension *which are the identity on base field (lower field)*. My aim is to understand what happens if we remove this condition of being the identity on the base field. Still then, can we obtain a one-to-one correspondence, as posted in question?

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Here's a case where this is particularly clear: if $F$ is a normal extension of its prime field, then **every** field automorphism of $E$ will send $F$ to itself.

For example, consider $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Then $\mathrm{Aut}(E|F)$, according to your definition, consists of all four automorphisms of $E$,
$$\mathrm{Aut}(E|F)=\{\mathrm{id}_E,\sigma,\psi,\sigma\psi\}\cong(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2\quad\text{ where }\quad \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\sigma(\sqrt{2})=-\sqrt{2}}{\sigma(\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3}}\quad \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\psi(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}}{\psi(\sqrt{3})=-\sqrt{3}}$$
whereas the only fields $K$ with $E\supseteq K\supseteq F$ are $K=E$ and $K=F$.